# why mongo count doesn't add up?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, exists

Does anyone know why mongodb returns strange result count when performing the next 3 queries? It seems that the result of the first and second counts should be equal to the third, but it does not. All I do is count the number of docs that contain a certain field + the ones that do not contain that field.. I expect this to be equal to the total number of docs:

```
> db.col1.find({f1:{$exists:false}}).count()
0
> db.col1.find({f1:{$exists:true}}).count()
267837
> db.col1.count()
268185
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you have a sparse index on f1 field?
If that is true, try this and see if they match:

```
db.col1.find({f1:{$exists:false}}).hint({f1:1}).count()
db.col1.find({f1:{$exists:false}}).hint({_id:1}).count()
```